# How do I extract the data (rows) in PostgresQL queryies?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, format, rows

Good Morning guys,

Im stucking on extract data from the PostgresQL queries.

I made query like this

```
pool.query(' SELECT * FROM images_info where id < 50', genericQueryHandler(res));
```

The data sent back format is like this

```
{
"command": "SELECT",
"rowCount": 49,
"oid": null,
"rows": [...],
"fields": [],
"_parsers": [],
"_types": {},
"RowCtor": null,
"rowAsArray": false
}
```

I only need the data in "rows". How do I extract the "rows"?    I tried  *limit*, *group by*, it doesn't work. Could you guys help me ? Very appreciate your time and help

Comment: Please tag your client API.

Comment: Could you clarify what's the meaning of " tag your client API"?

Comment: Are you using Node?

Comment: Well, you are using some kind of programming language and some kind of library to connect to the database. You should [edit] the question and add tags for these.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please mention which programming language you are running this code with: `pool.query(' SELECT * FROM images_info where id < 50', genericQueryHandler(res));`